# Apache Tomcat deployment WebSocket client can only connect to my server on localhost

Tags: java, tomcat, amazon-ec2

I am using AWS EC2 server having tomcat running on port 8080. When I deployed a war file with `ws://localhost/chat`, chat is running fine. But when I replaced localhost with my elastic ip, it throws error -

> WebSocket connection to ws://My_elastic_ip:8080/chat failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200.

Tried:

1. Tomcat is running separate, not behind apache.
2. port is open
3. No firewall restrict
4. No proxy used.

Please help.

Comment: Sounds like you're running Tomcat on localhost instead of 0.0.0.0

Comment: I am using following connector string but no luck.<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               URIEncoding="UTF-8"
               redirectPort="8443"
               address="0.0.0.0"/>

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that I am able to access my tomcat page from my elastic IP.

Comment: Finally resolved. Issue was, websocket-api.jar and tomcat7-websocket.jar are missing in lib directory of tomcat. I have added it and it works like a charm.